# Getting Rid of Nil Class Error in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-columns

I currently have a table that is split into 4 columns as such:

```
  <table id="customers">
<tr>
  <th><em class='require'></em><%= Release.columns_hash['version'].human_name  -%></th>
  <th><em class='require'></em><%= Release.columns_hash['version'].human_name  -%></th>
  <th><em class='require'></em><%= Release.columns_hash['version'].human_name  -%></th>
  <th><em class='require'></em><%= Release.columns_hash['version'].human_name  -%></th>
</tr>
<% @releases.in_groups_of(4).each do |releasesplit| %>
<tr>
   <% releasesplit.each do |release| %>
   <td align="center"><%= release.version %></td>
   <% end %>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

However the problem is whenever I add another entry to the table that is not divisible by 4 I get the error: `undefined method version' for nil:NilClass`

Any Ideas how to fix this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like one of  your releases in `@releases` variable is `nil`.

You can do this:
`@releases.compact.in_groups_of(4).each do ...`

`Array#compact` returns a copy of the original array with `nil` elements removed.

However, I strongly suggest you investigate why one of those is nil in the first place.

This is not the issue of grouping, since this is how grouping works:

```
irb(main):002:0> [1,2,3].each_slice(2) {|group| puts group.inspect}
[1, 2]
[3]
=> nil
```

(`in_groups_of` is just an ActiveSupport alias for `each_slice`)

Comment: I did not know about `compact`. Nice!

Comment: I don't have a nil element, its just that the array have 30 values and when ruby tried to split in into lets say 4 groups, 28/4 = 7, so 7 values per column. but when it reaches array number 31 it tries to get the value, but it hasent been created yet so nil is returned. But compact did it for me. Thanks :)

Comment: That's not how in_groups_of works. I'm pretty sure  you have a nil element. I've updated my answer.